# Capitalize the first letter of each word in a string in Python

Tags: python, string

Having a slight problem with this function in Python that's supposed to return the first letter of every word in a string  capitalized and everything else lowercased:

```
def titleize(phrase):
    split_phrase = phrase.split()

    for word in split_phrase:
        word.capitalize()

    return ' '.join(split_phrase)
```

`titleize('oNLy cAPITALIZe fIRSt')` -> `oNLy cAPITALIZe fIRSt`

Clearly the issue is with the loop over the phrase (I think) that is being split and I suspect it's not mutating but rather creating something new but I'm stuck trying to fix it.

Comment: The issue here is that you aren't saving it when you do `word.capitalize()` so still `split_phrase` has not been updated, but see below of how to use the built-in `str.title` function

Answer (score 13):

Might I suggest the use of the built-in `str.title()` function?

```
def titleize(phrase):
    capitalize_first = phrase.title()
    return capitalize_first
    
print(titleize('oNLy cAPITALIZe fIRSt'))
```

Output:

```
Only Capitalize First
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't assigning the result anywhere -- the `split_phrase` variable doesn't change at any point.

You could use `str.title()` as suggested by @pythonenthusiast, or use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to simplify your current approach:

```
def titleize(phrase):
    return ' '.join([word.capitalize() for word in phrase.split()])
```

The corrected version of your original code could look like this:

```
def titleize(phrase):
    split_phrase = phrase.split()
    result = []
    for word in split_phrase:
        result.append(word.capitalize())
    return ' '.join(result)
```

Here, a new `result` list is created, and in each iteration, we append the changed word to the list. At the end, we `join` and return the new `result` list.